# C++ Compile-Error C4430

Tags: c++, c++14

The Code shows 2 template-based functions which actually look fine. Both of them have the same syntax but only one of them is valid. I've been trying different kinds of implementations but none of them worked with the first one. And before you ask: I found no solution which helped me...

But here have a look at the code:

```
 #pragma once

#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#ifdef WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#endif //WIN32
#include <string>

namespace util {

    /* ############### */
    /* #             # */
    /* # For strings # */
    /* #             # */
    /* ############### */



    template<class T = std::string>
    bool hasPrefix(const T& string, const, T& prefix);

    template<class T = std::string>
    bool hasPostfix(const T& string, const T& postfix);

}

template<class T>
bool util::hasPrefix(const T& string, const T& prefix) {
     //CODE
}

template<class T>
bool util::hasPostfix(const T& string, const T& prefix) {
    //CODE
}
```

Now Visual Studio gives me this Error when I try to compile:

> Error C4430: Missing type-specifier - int assumed!

But only for hasPrefix(...) and not for hasPostfix(...)!
I tried to implement it without static_assert(...) or with the for(...)-loop.
Changing the header or anything else didn't help and I must admit that this Error doesn't even make sense to me because the second template-function works pretty well.

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class T = std::string>
bool hasPrefix(const T& string, const, T& prefix);
//                                   ^
```

Pay more attention to what you're doing.

The typo is obvious from simply looking at the declaration that works and the declaration that doesn't.

Comment: Thank you, how could I not see that ?  :/